# RSelenium: replacing xpath with variable in R

Tags: r, selenium, xpath

I try to replace xpath in the below code with variable in R. (I'm doing this because I will use it to do for loop.

```
> webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath' , 
    '//*[@id="dashboard-table-body"]/tr[3]')
```

I create a variable in R as shown below.

```
a <- paste0("'" , "/" , "/*" , "[@id=" , '"dashboard-table-body"' ,"]" , "/tr[",3,"]")

    > a
[1] "'//*[@id=\"dashboard-table-body\"]/tr[3]"
```

Output using variable as input.

```
webElem3 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath' , a)
Error:   Summary: InvalidSelector
         Detail: Argument was an invalid selector (e.g. XPath/CSS).
         class: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException
```

But this works.

```
webElem3 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath' ,  '//*[@id="dashboard-table-body"]/tr[3]')
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an *extra single quote* at the beginning making the expression invalid:

```
"'//*[@id=\"dashboard-table-body\"]/tr[3]"
 ^HERE
```

Demo from the Chrome console:

```
> $x("'//*[@id=\"dashboard-table-body\"]/tr[3]")
VM11825:215 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string ''//*[@id="dashboard-table-body"]/tr[3]' is not a valid XPath expression.(…)$x @ VM11825:215bound @ VM11825:18(anonymous function) @ VM11832:1
> $x("//*[@id=\"dashboard-table-body\"]/tr[3]")
[]
```